# How to get rid of this gray line when joining head and body meshes?

Tags: modeling, texturing, transparency

I downloaded the Facebuilder plugin and I tried to join the mesh with a body I had already. I removed the faces of the head and bridged the missing particles with my facebuilder head instead, but there's a grayish line that shows where I connected the head and body. I changed all the colors to the same colors to make sure it wasn't a texture issue. I know it's a small thing that can probably go unnoticed but if there's a way to fix it I'd rather know.

[image: Small line in mid-neck area.]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. If you are certain that this is not a texture issue, have you tried used the Smooth brush in Sculpt mode to smooth out the vertices where you joined the two meshes together?

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to ask for details in comments. thx

Comment: Hi Slickred, thank you for the warm welcome! Yes I used the smooth brush! I uploaded the blend file for people to use. :)

Comment: Hi Chris. just uploaded it.

Comment: Just remove the materials, specifically *FBHead_preview_mat* and *Toenails.002* and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's just that your viewport display colors are different:

[image]

[image]

You can either reset them or switch the *Viewport Shading* color from *Material* to *Object*:

[image]

Comment: I tried this and works in viewport both solid and material view. but when i render, it still shows this problem.

Comment: because these are 2 different materials, I'm just explaining why they don't display the same color in Solid mode when they should by default, he may want to give the 2 parts the same materials to fix the problem